# JQuery DatePicker conflict in Joomla 3 website

Tags: jquery, datepicker, joomla3.0

Sorry, I'm not a programmer and really can't find how to handle this...

On a Joomla 3.3.0 website (http://lantanaweb.com/savoy-sofia/sofia/) I added a custom HTML code module (it means adding JS and scripts to Joomla modules) to show a datepicker in a booking form. But the date picker do not show up as it should.

Moreover, after adding this module, the full page JQuery slideshow module stopped working.

Then I installed the JQuery Easy Plugin to solve JQuery related conflicts, and the slideshow was actually fixed.

But I can't still make the datepicker show as it is supposed to do.
My joomla custom HTML module code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="css/overcast/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form action="https://reservations.verticalbooking.com/reservation_hotel.htm" method="post" name="myform" id="myform" target="_blank" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onsubmit="invia_form();_gaq.push(['_linkByPost', this]);" >


                  <!-- ###################### -->
                  <!-- PARAMETERS TO CUSTOMIZE -->
                  <input name="gg" id="gg" value="" type="hidden">
                  <input name="mm" id="mm" value="" type="hidden">
                  <input name="aa" id="aa" value="" type="hidden">
                  <input name="id_albergo" value="312" type="hidden">
                  <input name="lingua_int" value="ita" type="hidden">
                  <input name="dc" value="710" type="hidden">
                  <input name="id_stile" value="9456" type="hidden">
                  <input name="headvar" value="ok" type="hidden">
                  <input name="graph_be" value="4" type="hidden">


<div id="arrival_date" class="blocco">
    <div class="label">Data di Arrivo</div>                
    <div class="tendina">
        <input id="datepicker" type="text" value="" >
    </div>
    </div>
<div id="nights" class="blocco">
    <div class="label">Notti</div>                
    <div class="tendina">
        <select class="select" name="notti_1" >
            <option value="1" selected>1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="rooms" class="blocco">
    <div class="label">Camere</div>                
    <div class="tendina">
        <select class="select" name="tot_camere">
            <option value="1" selected>1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="adults" class="blocco">
    <div class="label">Adulti</div>                
    <div class="tendina">
        <select class="select" name="tot_adulti">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="children" class="blocco">
    <div class="label">Bambini</div>                
    <div class="tendina">
        <select class="select" name="tot_bambini" >
            <option value="0" selected >0</option>      
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="search" class="blocco">
  <input id="button" type="submit" value="cerca" />
  </input>
</div>
<div id="cancella"><a href="https://reservations.verticalbooking.com/reservation_hotel.htm?id_albergo=312&dc=710&lingua_int=ita&headvar=ok&id_stile=9456&graph_be=4&cancel=pren">Annulla/Modifica Prenotazione</a></div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
var now = new Date();
var today = now.getDate() + '/' + (now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + now.getFullYear();
$('#datepicker').val(today);
});

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: "0", showOtherMonths: true, selectOtherMonths: true, altField: "#gg",  altFormat: "dd" });
});
function invia_form()
{
var data =  $( "#datepicker" ).attr('value');
//alert(data);

data = data.split('/');

$('#gg').attr({value:data[0]});
$('#mm').attr({value:data[1]});
$('#aa').attr({value:data[2]});

//alert($('#gg').attr('value')+' - '+$('#mm').attr('value')+' - '+$('#aa').attr('value'));
//$('#myform').submit();
}
</script>
```

Although I read a few posts related on the forum, I really don't know where to start from... Any help would be highly appreciated... Thanks!

Edit 1: 
The error is:

```
$(...).datepicker is not a function related code (line 435) is: $( 
"#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: "0", showOtherMonths: true, 
selectOtherMonths: true, altField: "#gg",   altFormat: "dd" });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share any errors appearing in your browser console.

Comment: thanks! after I changed according to your suggestions below, I only get error: 
$(...).datepicker is not a function

related code (line 435) is:
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: "0", showOtherMonths: true, selectOtherMonths: true, altField: "#gg", altFormat: "dd" });

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the other jQuery in the page, it's using the alias `jQuery` rather than `$`. Using `$` probably causes conflicts with MooTools or other JavaScript libraries.

Convert your code from, for example, this:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: "0", showOtherMonths: true, selectOtherMonths: true, altField: "#gg",  altFormat: "dd" });
});
```

to this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: "0", showOtherMonths: true, selectOtherMonths: true, altField: "#gg",  altFormat: "dd" });
});
```

Notice the `jQuery` alias at the start of the function, and the `$` in parentheses. Any other jQuery code that's not inside this wrapper function must use `jQuery`, and not `$`. You can probably just move it all inside with no ill effects.

Actually, the [**jQuery Easy extension docs**](http://www.simplifyyourweb.com/index.php/developers-corner/90-solving-jquery-jquery-and-jquery-mootools-conflict-issues-with-the-jquery-easy-plugin) cover this, too. Take a look at the "But wait..." section.

Comment: hello, I did substitute $ in function and document. most probably I should have substituted some place else, as the result is different now, but still not ok... I wonder if I should replace the Dollar symbol everywhere, or else.
I didn't really understand the JQuery Easy workaround... my fault clearly...

Comment: hello, after editing I tried uninstalling and reinstalling JQuery Easy plugin... and it worked! or so it seems... as the datepicker is now visible, although date variable is not passed properly...

Comment: You could use [`jQuery.noconflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) to prevent `"$"` conflict of jQuery and Mootools